# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'isRightSidebarExpanded')

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to convert a template for use with nuxt.js

This attribute gives me this error

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'isRightSidebarExpanded')

`@click="$store.global.isRightSidebarExpanded = false"`

Here is the JS file : https://lineone.piniastudio.com/js/app.js

I imported it into nuxt.js with this line in nuxt.config.js

```
script: [
     {src: '/js/app.js', body: false, defer:true}
     ]
```

Then nuxt.js shows me this error because it seems to ignore the client side javascript file, while it works perfectly without nuxt.js but with only static HTML/JS files in local

You can see here that the site is working normally (Laravel) https://lineone.piniastudio.com/

Some HTML variables (such as "activeTab") are also not defined

> Property or method "activeTab" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Propertie

But everything works when I just keep HTML/JS/CSS and make it work without nuxt.js in static mode

Comment: Can you try to log to the console the value of `store.global`?

Comment: In the Chromse console : "Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined"
But I have the same result on https://lineone.piniastudio.com/ which works

Comment: well that should give you a hint - you are trying to access a property of an undefined object. If `store` is not defined, neither is its `global` property, neither is the `isRightSidebarExpanded` property of global.

Comment: I'm trying to access the store variable on the version of the site that works (via the Chrome console) and I can't either, you can try on https://lineone.piniastudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to change the store data directly.
Vuex use [Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) to commit changes to the store state.

1. add a Mutation that change the **isRightSidebarExpanded** property

```
  mutations: {
    isRightSidebarExpanded(state , payload) {
      // mutate state
      state.isRightSidebarExpanded = payload ;
    }
  }
```

2. now you can call your Mutation

```
 @click="$store.global.commit('isRightSidebarExpanded',false)"
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For the undefined issue :
-check if the $store.global property exist 
-check if you are using the store (main.js)

```
app.use(store);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory it may be because the javascript is being referenced before it has been loaded. I had a similar problem dealing with VR/AR frame javascript that I loaded in the same way. I resolved this by using the callback option as described here in this article (Read to the end!).

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/

Hope that helps!
-Brian